# TFS 2015 Build definition - override Build number with variables

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

We use a nice $(date:yyyy.MM.dd)$(rev:.r) build number format in our day-to-day agile sprints. However, the release must be numbered with a simpler 1.0.0.rev schema.

Ideally, I would like to give the build number as a variable, which would be automatically expanded in the "queue build" dialog, where it would be possible to be overriden. How can it be done?

I tried moving the $(date:yyyy.MM.dd)$(rev:.r) format to a variable, and use that variable in the general tab, and got error 400.

Comment: Why you want to give the build number as a variable? Did you just want to keep $(date:yyyy.MM.dd)$(rev:.r)? Or you want to use the build number in your build steps?

Comment: @Patrick-MSFT I would like to be able to override the version number (and change the normal format with a "release" format) when queuing a new build - just like I'm able to change any other build variable.

Comment: You can't directly change the value in the  queue build of the version number.If you want to change the majorversion or minorversion. You need to manually change it in the definition. Detail ways you can refer this blog  http://incyclesoftware.com/2015/06/vnext-build-awesomeness-managing-version-numbers/ in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could directly use [Environment variables](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/define/variables#environment-variables) such as `Build.BuildNumber` /`BUILD_BUILDNUMBER`

Using this just equals to the name of the completed build. You can specify the build number format that generates this value on the [General tab](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/define/general).

If you just want to generate custom build numbers like 1.0.0.rev schema in TFS Build vNext. You can take a look at below blogs:

- [Generate custom build numbers in TFS Build vNext](http://blog.ehn.nu/2015/10/generate-custom-build-numbers-in-tfs-build-vnext/)
- [Managing vNext build Version Numbers](http://blogs.incyclesoftware.com/2015/06/vnext-build-awesomeness-managing-version-numbers/)

Comment: The second link gives a way to implement it - override variables from a build step. Thanks!

Comment: second link is dead... :(

Answer (score 2):

This is very simple.

1) Just create a Powershell script like this

```js
$FinalVersion=Some-Function-To-Calculate-Version
$BuildDefName = $Env:BUILD_DEFINITIONNAME
Write-Host "##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]$($BuildDefName)-$($FinalVersion)"
```

2) In your vNext build definition, for "Build number format" just set it to anything.  It doesn't matter because the Build Number will be overwritten.

3) In the same vNext build definition steps, add the first step as a Powershell step, and set your script from step 1 to be executed.  You can later customize if you want to pass variables in order to calculate your build number.

4) Queue your build and see the results.